# Draw different colored bar chart matlab

Tags: matlab

I draw a bar chart based on some values but I was wondering if I can draw it with different color. So for example if the accuracy is less than 25% the bar turns red, if it lies between 25% and 50% turns yellow and it turns green if the accuracy is more than 50% .. Any Help?

My code:

```
 x = [0.1 0.5 1 2 3];
 y = [2.0407   10.2108   19.8171   36.6688   52.2866];
 xplot = 1:numel(x); 
 figure;
 bar(xplot,y);
 ylabel('Accuracy');
 xlabel('level');
 set(gca,'XTick', xplot); 
 set(gca,'XTickLabel', x);
 ylim([0 100]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20860-how-to-use-colormap-for-different-bars) answer:

```
x = [0.1 0.5 1 2 3];
y = [2.0407   10.2108   19.8171   36.6688   52.2866];
xplot = 1:numel(x); 

fHand = figure;
aHand = axes('parent', fHand);
hold(aHand, 'on')

for i=xplot
    if x(i) < 0.25
        bar(i, y(i), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'red')
    elseif x(i) <= 0.5
        bar(i, y(i), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'yellow')
    elseif x(i) > 0.5
        bar(i, y(i), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'green')
    end
end

set(gca,'XTick', xplot); 
set(gca,'XTickLabel', x);

ylabel('Accuracy');
xlabel('level');

ylim([0 100]);
```

Which gets you:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfect, Can we change the Y axis to be only 3 values: VeryBad( less than 25%), bad(25% and 50% ) and Good(more than 50%) regardless the exact percentage?

Comment: @SMH, that's a different question (and the answer is, have a look at `set(gca, 'YTick', ...)` and `set(gca, 'YTickLabel', ...)`. If the answer helped you, you should upvote and/or accept it.